# Is there a way to clear out embedded Bitmap assets in AS3/AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, garbage-collection, adobe

first time posting on here.

I'm creating an AIR 3.0 app.

For a lot of my graphical assets I'm using the Flex embed metadata to embed bitmap objects as Classes and then instantiating them.

The problem is that it seems these never get garbage collected. I haven't found much info online but I've seen a couple of posts that seem to confirm this.

Anytime one of my classes gets instantiated that has these embedded assets, they always create new instances of the Bitmaps and BitmapDatas rather than reusing what's already in memory. This is a huge problem for memory. And I can't find any way of de-referenciong them or getting them to leave memory.

So the only solution I can think is to just load the graphics from disk rather than using the embed tag. But I'd rather not do this seeing as how when the app is packaged and installed, all of those graphcial assets will be on the end users computer rather than contained within the SWF.

Anyoen run into this? Have a solution? Or an alternate solution than the one I can think of?

Thanks!
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess this is expected behaviour, because the new operator should always create new objects. But those new objects should get garbage collected, just the asset class will not, since it is a class.

You could build a cache that acts like a singleton factory. You request your image by specifying an id, the cache then either creates that image if it doesn't exist already, or just return the single instance if it does. It's been a while since I last coded ActionScript, so maybe you should take this as pseudo-code ;)

```
public class Cache {

    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    [Embed(source="example.gif")]
    public static var ExampleGif:Class;

    /**
     * The single instance of the cache.
     */
    private static var instance:Cache;

    /**
     * Gets the Cache instance.
     *
     * @return
     *     The Cache
     */
    public static function getInstance():Cache {
        if (Cache.instance == null) {
            Cache.instance = new Cache();
        }
        return Cache.instance;
    }

    /**
     * The cached assets are in here.
     */
    private var dictionary:Dictionary

    public function Chache() {
        if (Cache.instance != null) {
            throw new Error("Can not instanciate more than once.");
        }
        this.dictionary = new Dictionary();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the single instantiated asset its name.
     *
     * @param assetName
     *     The name of the variable that was used to store the embeded class
     */
    public function getAsset(assetName:String):Object {
        if (this.dictionary[assetName] == null) {
            var AssetClass = getDefinitionByName(assetName) as Class;
            this.dictionary[assetName] = new AssetClass();
        }
        return this.dicionary[assetName];
    }

}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
public class Example {

    public static function main() {
        Bitmap exampleGif1 = Cache.getInstance().getAsset("ExampleGif") as Bitmap;
        Bitmap exampleGif2 = Cache.getInstance().getAsset("ExampleGif") as Bitmap;
        trace("both should be the same instance: " + (exampleGif1 == exampleGif2));
    }

}
```

I didn't test this, so let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is dispose() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?#dispose()

If you decide to go with a caching system, here is a link with some code that *is* tested http://thanksmister.com/2009/01/29/flex-imagecache-a-cheap-way-to-cache-images/ . The link it has to another technique, using SuperImage, is broken, but I managed to find this http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/superImage/app.html .